# Three tables association

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, database, join, ruby-on-rails-5

I have three tables that rely on each other in order to retrieve the correct taxes for a product type. Bellow I'll describe the tables and their functionality in detail:

- **ProductType:** Determines the type of product that's being sold. It holds information about the product, such as: name, dimensions, weight, price, etc.
- **Taxes:** Determines the taxes percentages for each product type for each province it would be sold to. It has many types of taxes.
- **Province:** Determines the province/state to which the product is being sold to. It has information about the province such as acronym, name, country, etc. It's also used to determine regions of coverage of other objects(tables) and locations of suppliers, salesman, etc.

My question is: how do I structure this in the DB as well as in my Ruby on Rails project, since the taxes that I want to get depend not only to the type of the product, but to the province/state as well?

I do not wish to have multiple records of the same province, one for each product type or multiple records of the same product type, one for each province or taxes.

Notice: All three tables have many to many relationships between themselves.

Comment: I suspect that others have been faced with this conundrum. What did they do?

Comment: @Strawberry Believe me, I've searched. Didn't find anything that I could understand out there and apply to my particular issue. But if you know of any, please inform me.

Comment: E.g.: https://i.stack.imgur.com/RHeu8.jpg

Comment: See my answer, it seems Tax should not have has_many towards Province and ProductType, but should belong to it. This will create redundancy in the actual tax rate... if you would like to normalize that, you should create a separate table to store the TaxRates, and rename the Tax model to TaxRule

Comment: Not a duplicate, that other question works with 2 tables, In Brazil there is a classification called "NCM" (I've translated to productType for ease of understanding) that adds another dimension to the issue.

Comment: @Strawberry I've found an answer with the help of Bo-oz and It is very different from the answer in that post. Please reopen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
class ProductType
  has_many :taxes
end

class Tax
  belongs_to :product_type
  belongs_to :province
end

class Province
  has_many :taxes
end
```

When looking for the Tax for a certain ProductType, do something like:

```
ProductType.find(123).taxes.where(province: 'XYZ')
```

Comment: This way is correct. I changed it a bit: I transformed the `Taxes` table into a join table for `Provinces` and `ProductTypes`, then I use  `has_many through` associations in provinces and products to access the taxes from each whenever necessary. Thank you @bo-oz .

Comment: And have a look at my remark, you might benefit from normalizing it even further by adding a third model TaxRate, that has_many :taxes.

Comment: I wrote it wrong, indeed I did make the fourth table as a join table for the first three (`Taxation'). That one holds the ids of each of the others and so I don't have to create multiple redundant products, provinces or even taxes.